# Android ksoap2 Session cookies managment

Tags: java, android, .net, web-services, ksoap2

my application suppose to connect a web service and active some of his functions.
first, the application activate a "Login" function that gets as arguments username and password, the function search the user name and the password in a database and returning me if im logged in or not. and creating a session vars for me like:

```
Session["Username"] = User.Username;

Session["FullName"] = User.FullName;
```

and more...

and than i want to active another webservice function - UpdateProfile
that change my profile values on the database.

so, my application has a class with some private classes (asynctasks)
and every asynctask is responsible for one function in the webservice.

for example - the login asynctask:

```
private class LoginAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, User>
{

    private String METHODNAME = "Login";
    private String SOAPACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Login";
```

and more...

in this login asynctask i parse the comming back cookies like this:

```
cookies is a HashMap<String, String>();

    try
    {

        //respHeaders = trans.call(SOAPACTION, envelope, null);
        reshttpHeaders = trans.call(SOAPACTION, envelope, null);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //connection error.
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
   cookies.clear();
        if (reshttpHeaders!=null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < reshttpHeaders.size(); i++) {
                HeaderProperty hp = (HeaderProperty)reshttpHeaders.get(i);
                String key = hp.getKey();
                String value = hp.getValue();
                if (key!=null && value!=null) {
                    if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("set-cookie")){
                        String cookieString = value.substring(0,value.indexOf(";") );

                        cookies.put(cookieString.substring(0, cookieString.indexOf("=")),cookieString.substring(cookieString.indexOf("=")+1) );
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

and than, in another asynctask called UpdateProfileAsynctask
im sending this cookie like this:

```
        List<HeaderProperty> httpHeaders = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
        for (String cookie:cookies.keySet()) {
            httpHeaders.add(new HeaderProperty("Cookie", cookie + "=" + cookies.get(cookie)));
        }

        try
        {

            //trans.call(SOAPACTION, envelope, reqHeaders);
            trans.call(SOAPACTION, envelope, httpHeaders);
        }
```

when i try to catch this packets with wireshark i see that the cookie that i get is:
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=kmwn4l2qzc0k1anfk1du4ty1; path=/; HttpOnly\r\n

and my cookie that i send is:
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=kmwn4l2qzc0k1anfk1du4ty1\r\n

The problem is that the webservice dont recognize me (the second request is in the 20 minutes period).

this part of the code in the webservice running:

```
if (Session["Username"] == null)
    return "Cant Update profile now, Your connection seems to be timeout";
```

and i get this message all time. but its stange that sometimes its working :/

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fix my problems after reading your questions, thank you.
My code is like the folloiwng:

HeaderProperty headerPropertySessionId = new HeaderProperty("Cookie", "key1=value1");
List headerPropertyList = new ArrayList();
headerPropertyList.add(headerPropertySessionId);